# Como tener una posicion por defecto en el scroll

Tags: html, css

Estoy usando un div con `overflow-y: scroll;`y requiero que por defecto al cargar la aplicacion se encuentre al final del div, no al principio, se que podria hacerlo con js usando `scroll(0, 50000)`al cargar la pagina o algo por el estilo, o tambien poniendo un ID al ultimo elemento y usando `#` pero, no hay una manera mas eficiente de hacer esto?

este es mi HTML

```html
<div class="chat" id="chat">
    <div class="chat__header">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-comments chat__header-i"></i>
        <h4 class="chat__header-h4">Chat</h4>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus chat__header-i"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="chat__container">
        <div class="chat__container-messages">
            <div class="message__container message__container-send">
                <div class="message__send">
                    <h6 class="sended">Tu</h6>
                    <p class="message__send-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, aut?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-received">
                <div class="message__received">
                    <h6 class="sended">Omar</h6>
                    <p class="message__received-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, officia!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-send">
                <div class="message__send">
                    <h6 class="sended">Tu</h6>
                    <p class="message__send-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, aut?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-received">
                <div class="message__received">
                    <h6 class="sended">Omar</h6>
                    <p class="message__received-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, officia!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-send">
                <div class="message__send">
                    <h6 class="sended">Tu</h6>
                    <p class="message__send-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, aut?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-received">
                <div class="message__received">
                    <h6 class="sended">Omar</h6>
                    <p class="message__received-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, officia!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-received">
                <div class="message__received">
                    <h6 class="sended">Omar</h6>
                    <p class="message__received-content">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message__container message__container-send">
                <div class="message__send">
                    <h6 class="sended">Omar</h6>
                    <p class="message__send-content">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat__container-input">
            <input type="text" class="messages__input" placeholder="Aa">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane chat__input-i"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y este

```css
.chat{
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.chat__header{
  border-top-left-radius: 10px ;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px ;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--main-red);
}

.chat__header-h4{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--main-text);
}

.chat__container{
  width: 100%;
}

.chat__container-input{
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.chat__container-messages{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.messages__input{
  background: #F0F2F5;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 70%;
}

.chat__input-i{
  color: var(--actions-blue);
}

.message__container{
  font-size: .9375rem;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.message__send, .message__received{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 70%;
}
.message__send{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0084ff;
  border-radius: 18px 4px 18px 18px;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#chat .message__send p, #chat .message__received p, #chat .messages__input{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI' !important;
}

.message__received{
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 18px 18px 18px;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.message__send-content, .message__received-content{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.sended{
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
}

.message__container-send .sended{
  text-align: left;
}
.message__container-send{
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.message__container-received .sended{
  text-align: right;
}
.message__container-received{
  align-items: flex-start;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  pointer-events: all;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
  width:8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment,::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b3b3b3;;
  width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #999999;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

es el css de lo que tengo implementado, todo se gestiona desde el backend con node js asi que el chat no es mas que un partial, los 'Mensajes' son los que estoy usando de prueba para diseñar,

Comment: pon el codigo que tengas con lo que hayas intentado

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego ahi esta lo que voy hasta el momento, se puede notar que no es mas que una copia simplificada del chat de messenger

Comment: y cual es el div que queres que quede al final al scrollear?

Comment: o al final de la pagina?

Comment: el html es del div que estoy usando, tiene una position fixed para mantenerse en la parte inferior derecha siempre, la idea es que al ser un chat si yo cargo la pagina el automaticamente vaya al ultimo mensaje, en este caso, por defecto al cargar la posicion del scroll es el primer mensaje, no el ultimo

Answer (score 0):

Te sirve esto? es JS de frontend

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => { // al cargarse el dom
  window.scroll({ // hacemos scroll
    top: document.body.scrollHeight, // con scrollheight obtenemos el maximo numero de pixeles scrolleables 
    behavior: "smooth" // transicion
  })
})
```

Comment: al final decidi dejar de lado la facilidad eh irme por js

const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chatWindow')

chatWindow.scroll(0, chatWindow.scrollHeight)